# Como dividir todas as span .class por 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como fazer estas divisões e obter resultados diferentes para cada divisão. O resultado sai certo apenas para o primeiro preço e nos outros o resultado são todos iguais: 200.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ecwid").click(function() {
    var x = parseInt($('span.ecwid-productBrowser-price-value')[0].innerHTML.replace(',', '.').substr(2))
    $("span").append("<p>3x de " + x / 3 + "</p>")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='ecwid'>Teste</button><br><br>

<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$600,00</span>
<hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$800,00</span>
<hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$700,00</span>
<hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$500,00</span>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tens de iterar esses `span` com `spans.each(function() {` e depois usar o `this` para fazer contas e `.append()`.

Exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ecwid").click(function() {
    var spans = $('span.ecwid-productBrowser-price-value');
    spans.each(function() {
      var valor = parseInt(this.innerHTML.replace(',', '.').substr(2) / 3, 10);
      $(this).append("<p>3x de " + valor + "</p>")
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='ecwid'>Teste</button><br><br>

<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$600,00</span>
<hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$800,00</span>
<hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$700,00</span>
<hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$500,00</span>
<hr>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Era exatamente isso que precisa. Muito obrigado!